# Get a collection of items in document library/list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scripting

I'm new to Powershell. What I'm trying to do is get a list of all the documents in a document library. I have an absolute URL of the document library I want to process, for example.

Essentially what I want is a reference to the document library so I can send some CAML queries to it.

`http://sharepoint2013/sites/superdupersite/shared%20documents`

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$items = Get-SPList "http://sharepoint2013/sites/superdupersite/shared%20documents"

foreach ($item in $item) {
       #process
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How can I do this in powershell?

Comment: Main thing I want to be able to use an absolute URL to the library to get the contents.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Nothing is returned? A little more details about what is going wrong and anything you've tried to resolve the problem.

Comment: `Get-SPList` does not seem to work, I don't think this is the right function. Trying to look for one that will take my absolute URL to the list and return a collection of items in that List.

Comment: Define "does not seem to work". Do you get an error? Not the desired result? No result at all?

Comment: Get-SPList is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, or function. Is there a function similar?

Comment: Are you on the SharePoint server? (You have to be to execute SharePoint CmdLets.) Do you get an error when you execute `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell`? There are also other ways to get to SharePoint content. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe this could get you started? `http://sharepoint2013/_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx` `http://sharepoint2013/_vti_bin/lists.asmx` `http://sharepoint2013/_vti_bin/views.asmx`

Answer (score 2):

In your code will return "$items" will contain an SPList object if it works in the expected manner.
Try this:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$site =  Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint2013/sites/superdupersite/"
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists[Shared Documents] <Title of the list goes here>
$items = $list.GetItems()

foreach ($item in $items) {
   #process
}
```

Happy scripting =)

Comment: typo -> foreach ($item in $itemS) {